# Remove the overlap of the gridlines on markers

Tags: highcharts

I'm doing an areaspline chart where my gridlines on the x-axis are of the same colour as the background but different from the markers and the "information" background.

Here's a fiddle to exemplify: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ritadias/1xmw6uvr/4/)

I wanted the markers (and only the markers, the rest of the are would still have the gridline) to be "in front" of the gridlines so it's not cut in half.

```
xAxis: {
        ...
        gridZIndex: 4,
        ...
```

I have tried moving the gridZIndex, the problem is that when I make it a value smaller, the part in grey stops having the grid which is not the effect wanted (although the markers stop being cut in half.

<strike>Is what I'm trying to do possible?</strike>

Without modifying the DOM it's not possible, so that's what I ended up doing. So, after closing the highcharts, using jquery you can do this:

```
$('.highcharts-markers').insertAfter($('.highcharts-grid')[1]);
```

Meaning that I moved the white markers on top of the grid. Problem solved. 
(more suggestions to get around this are in the comment in this question)

Comment: Without modifying DOM I don't think so. Simply series is in one `<g>`-group, and axis in another. Now you want to display part of a group below and the rest above another group.  I think it would be easier to user Highcharts.renderer to draw that lines, or just use separate series (scatter with lineWidth=1) to display that lines.

Comment: Ended up modifying the Dom, thanks for the tip.