# Bring marker to front of grid line in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

Currenly i am able to make the chart with configuration in my jsfiddle. But one thing left is that i want the markers (points) display above the gridlines. As my research, the highchart marker does not have options for zIndex.

http://jsfiddle.net/ngoclamnn/jsegagwp/1/

Tried with this code:

```
function(chart){
   console.log(chart);
   chart.series[1].graph.toFront();
   chart.series[1].group.toFront();
   chart.series[1].markerGroup.toFront();
}
```

But it still not success. Hope that someone can help :)

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679812/remove-the-overlap-of-the-gridlines-on-markers), there doesn't appear to be a way to do this in the standard options. You would have to either draw the marker yourself using the highchart renderer, or amend the SVG that's generated in the DOM manually. Neither is straightforward. I'd suggest making a feature request to HighCharts directly.

Comment: Thanks! I will contact to highcharts suport team.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is not available in Highcharts because all series are in the same group. You could (as suggested in comments) manipulate `DOM`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qaytamvy/

*The solution might not work well for all cases - like dynamic chart changes, so just keep in mind this is more like a POC then a solid fix.*